# How to Map Portchannel to Interfaces via SNMP

Tags: port, snmp, channel

How do I get this result via SNMP?

show etherchannel summary

```
Group  Port-channel  Protocol    Ports
------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
1      Po1(RU)          -        Gi2/3(P)       Gi3/3(P)       
2      Po2(RU)          -        Gi2/4(P)       Gi3/4(P)       
3      Po3(SU)          -        Gi2/2(P)       Gi3/2(P)       
9      Po9(SU)          -        Gi2/12(P)      Gi3/12(P)      
421    Po421(SU)        -        Gi11/1(P)      Gi11/2(P)      Gi11/3(P)      
                             Gi11/4(P)      
422    Po422(SU)        -        Gi11/5(P)      Gi11/6(P)      Gi11/7(P)      
                             Gi11/8(P)      
423    Po423(SU)        -        Te12/1(P)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but researching something similar I came across [this Cisco forums post](https://supportforums.cisco.com/message/3957914). It reports the following objects in `IEEE8023-LAG-MIB`:

```
IEEE8023-LAG-MIB::dot3adAggPortSelectedAggID.28 = INTEGER: 337
IEEE8023-LAG-MIB::dot3adAggPortSelectedAggID.82 = INTEGER: 337

IEEE8023-LAG-MIB::dot3adAggPortAttachedAggID.28 = INTEGER: 337
IEEE8023-LAG-MIB::dot3adAggPortAttachedAggID.82 = INTEGER: 337

ifName.28 = Gi2/4
ifName.82 = Gi3/10
ifName.337 = Po1
```

In the same environment the `show etherchannel summary` command will result in:

```
+------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------+
| Group|Port-channel |Protocol   | Ports                           |
+------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------+
|  1   | Po1(SU)     | LACP      | Gi2/4(P)       Gi3/10(P)        |
+------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

for PAGP protocol there is a table  pagpEtherChannelTable where pagpGroupIfIndex points to common virtual port